# How to display geodjango rest api response on react leaflet Map

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, geodjango, react-leaflet

I have the following response from django rest:

```
[
   {
    "area": 0.0,
    "perimeter": 0.0,
    "town_name": "Cheptais",
    "town_id": 4,
    "town_type": "Market Centres",
    "geom": "SRID=4326;MULTIPOINT (34.4500007629395 0.800000011920929)"
},
{
    "area": 0.0,
    "perimeter": 0.0,
    "town_name": "Dadaab",
    "town_id": 3,
    "town_type": "Trading Centre",
    "geom": "SRID=4326;MULTIPOINT (40.3199996948242 0.070000000298023)"
},
{
    "area": 0.0,
    "perimeter": 0.0,
    "town_name": "Eldas",
    "town_id": 4,
    "town_type": "Market Centres",
    "geom": "SRID=4326;MULTIPOINT (39.5499992370605 2.52999997138977)"
}
]
```

Fetching the endpoint with axios this way:

```
await axios
  .get("/api/gis/areas/", headers)
  .then((response) => {
    this.setState({ places: response.data });
    console.log(response.data);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

}

```
 const handleEachFeature = (feature, layer) => {
  layer.bindPopup('<font size="4">' + feature.properties.town_name);
}
```

Using react leaflet, I create a map instance as follows:

```
<Map className="map" onEachFeature={handleEachFeature} style={{height:'100%',width:'100%'}}>
      <GeoJSON data={places}/>
</Map>
```

However, this does not overlay the api response on my map.. I'm I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as i mentioned on the comments,you have to convert the wkt to geojson in order for this to work, there are several solution to achieve such conversion but the easiest one here is to import wicket library (just use npm install wicket), also you need to create the  with a unique key, here is a working component from your same data (note i'm not using axios as i test the data locally), :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './styles/styles.css'
import {Map,TileLayer,GeoJSON} from 'react-leaflet'
import './leaflet/leaflet.css'
import Wkt from 'wicket'
import L from 'leaflet'
import Data from '../../Data/wkt_file.json'

import icon from 'leaflet/dist/images/marker-icon.png';
import iconShadow from 'leaflet/dist/images/marker-shadow.png';

// this is for maker to show up:
let DefaultIcon = L.icon({
    iconUrl: icon,
    shadowUrl: iconShadow
});

L.Marker.prototype.options.icon = DefaultIcon;

export default class map extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            wkt_json_holder:[],
            json_ob:<></>,
            json_key:1, 
            tile:'https://tiles.stadiamaps.com/tiles/alidade_smooth_dark/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png',
        }
        this.setGeoJSON = this.setGeoJSON.bind(this)
        this.onEach = this.onEach.bind(this)
    }
    async componentDidMount(){
        await this.setState({wkt_json_holder:Data});
        this.setGeoJSON()
    }

    setGeoJSON=()=>{
        let json_data = this.state.wkt_json_holder.map(point=>{
            let wkt_geom = point['geom'].replace('SRID=4326;','')
            let wkt = new Wkt.Wkt();
            wkt.read(wkt_geom)
            let geojson_geom = wkt.toJson()
            let coords = geojson_geom['coordinates']
            let type = geojson_geom['type']
            let geojson_obj={
                "type": "Feature",
                "geometry": {
                    'type':type,
                    'coordinates':coords
                },
                "properties": {
                    "town_name": point['town_name'], "town_id": point['town_id'], "town_type":point['town_type'], "perimeter": point['perimeter'], "area": point['area']
                }
            }
              return geojson_obj
            }
              
            )
            console.log(json_data)
            let json_ob= <GeoJSON data={json_data} key={1} style={{color:'red'}} onEachFeature={this.onEach}/>
            this.setState({json_ob})
    }

    // handling Popups 
    onEach(feature,layer){
        console.log(feature)
        let PopupContent = `
            <Popup>
                <p>town id:${feature.properties.town_id}</p>
                <p>town name:${feature.properties.town_name}</p>
            </Popup>
        `
        layer.bindPopup(PopupContent)
    }

    render() {
                
        return (
        <div style={{width:'100%',height:'100%'}}>
            <Map center={[2.197035, 38.703588]} zoom={6} style={{width:'100%',height:'100%'}}>
                <TileLayer url={this.state.tile}/>
                {this.state.json_ob}
            </Map>
                
        </div>
        )
    }

    
}
```

Comment: Excuse me Khaleb, so when setting up a new GeoJSON component, where do I get the key? and how do I call the component inside the map?

Comment: produce it yourself, it just a unique random number, you can put it in the state and use it with the GeoJSON, for testing just use the key as 1, then you can use other things as Math module to generate it randomly.

Comment: so I don't need the places state? And how do I call it inside MAP?

Comment: no, you can set it as <GeoJSON key={1} data={...}>, but this won't be practical if you keep changing your data, if you put in the state you can change it dynamically as you fetch new data.

Comment: and to put it iniside the map, you can set a state property, when you fetch your data update that property (i can see you are using this.setState to do so, above i used a state property and named it json_ob ), then this same variable is used inside your map, so when you change the state the variable will be changed

Comment: Do you mind updating your answer with the code to render the MAP?

Comment: it throws an error  Line 202:26:  'new_json' is not defined  no-undef : if i change to this.state.new_json nothing happens

Comment: ok, it's this.state.new_json (i have been working with hooks for a while), let me check my previous code.

Comment: ok, i've tried it and it worked, then tried to use your same data, and it's obvious why it's not working, you have your data as a wkt, first you need to convert it to geojson format in order to work it out, give me a minute to figure it out.

Comment: updated with a complete working component from the same data.

Comment: So I have implemented your code and it's working, thank you ... now perhaps three more points of clarity.. 1. Is querying in the manner above okay or is heavy during rendering? because it lags quite a bit.  2. How can I query just one point from the data? 3. I need to do handleEachFeature to binpopup name of town on each feature click..my implementation as updated above doesn't work.

Comment: 3. updated to handle the popups,
1. and 2. generally you have two approaches, either to fetch all the data and filter it on the front end (the data here is coming as an array so you can use filter method or for loop with if statements to make a subset of the data according to a specific attribute within the data, each data pint is at the end a js object so you can access it's attributes), but as you mentioned this will become a problem if you have large data coming in..

Comment: the other way around is to make different endpoints in django rest and subset the data in the views (end results will be like http://localhost:8000/all for all data, http://localhost:8000/subset1 for subset1 and so on according to specific attributes in your data ..) then fetch on the frontend axios.get('http://localhost:8000/subset1') ..